# Phantom wallet Integration with React Native

Tags: react-native, integration, phantom-wallet

Is there any tutorials out there that will show how to integrate Phantom Wallet to React Native. I search it but it always shows the Phantom wallet to React App only. I also look on the documentation on Phantom wallet but there is no clear instruction for React Native.

I hope you will help me with this thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, phantom has two react-native repos available

1. https://github.com/phantom/deep-link-demo-app
2. https://github.com/phantom/deep-links-movie-tutorial

And an in depth guide here:
https://phantom.app/learn/blog/the-complete-guide-to-phantom-deeplinks#introduction